# I want to change the order of price details in cart

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, totals

Here is the screen short i want to change the order of the price details on cart page.
How can i achieve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Admin side goto...

> Store => Configuration => Sales => Sales => **Checkout Totals Sort
>   Order**

Set order as you want.

Comment: How can i hide tax in cart ?

Comment: For the hidden tax in a cart?  >  Follow the below path
Store => Configuration =>Sales => Tax => Shopping Cart Display Settings

"Display Full tax Summary" Set as 'NO'

Comment: It is set to no but it's still showing